# I can't configure spring cloud gateway from locator.enabled

Tags: spring, cloud, config, netflix-eureka, gateway

I made eureka server and eureka client but then I need to create an api

## gateway and for this you need to configure it using **spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.enabled** but it doesn’t see it

I tried to use consul but it didn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.